# Are images cached or not?

Tags: nginx, cache, apache2

I'm a bit perplexed on debugging of caching circumstances in the landscape of Apache (webserver) and Nginx (reverse proxy):

I'm trying to get into knowledge, whether images are properly cached or not.

**Image header from devtools** looks like:

[image]

**Diagnosis by Webpagetest** looks like:

[image]

But **devtools shows**, like images would be cached, like this (right column):

[image]

Is it possible to say something definitely, like "yes, images are properly cached" or "no, images aren' cached"? Or "not enough data"?

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining any cache control in your response headers. According to [RFC 7231, 4.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> The response to a GET request is cacheable; a cache MAY use it to
> satisfy subsequent GET and HEAD requests unless otherwise indicated
> by the `Cache-Control` header field ([Section 5.2 of [RFC7234]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2)).

You could use [`no-cache`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.2) to specify that the browser should not cache the images or e.g. [`max-age=2592000`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.8) to specify that they could be cached for a month. There's also [`Expires`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) for expressing the date/time after which the response is considered stale.

As there's no specific control for the cache, and HTTP/1.1 specification doesn't define a default caching behaviour, **browsers can cache your images as they wish**. From Ilya Grigorik on [HTTP Caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching):

> All HTTP requests that the browser makes are first routed to the
> browser cache to check whether there is a valid cached response that
> can be used to fulfill the request. If there's a match, the response
> is read from the cache, which eliminates both the network latency and
> the data costs that the transfer incurs.

Comment: Does it mean `images are currently cached, but this is because browser is able to understand what to cache despite missed cache rules`?

Answer (score 1):

I paid a visit to your website, and the scripts are cached by the browser.  The images are cached too, but not by the browser, but via javascript.  Check your scripts for image loading.